# How to securely synchronize encrypted data between a desktop and web app?

Tags: security, encryption

I am developing a multi-user desktop app that saves encrypted information using AES encryption with the key derived from the user’s password using PBKDF2. I plan to provide a web version of the app with a similar encryption system and the ability to connect a local user to an online user through a token. When a user adds something in the desktop app, it should be uploaded and saved in the online database.

However, I am facing a problem: when the server receives the data to encrypt and save, it doesn’t know the encryption key of that user since it doesn’t have access to their password (because they did not log in via the web app). How can I securely synchronize encrypted data between the desktop and web app while ensuring that the server does not need to save the user’s encryption key?

Comment: Have the data encrypted before uploading.

Comment: @MarekPuchalski if the online password is different from the local password, then the encryption keys would be different